# Multiple graphs with boxplots for range of X-values (ggplot2)

Tags: r, ggplot2, boxplot

I've been stuck on one particular problem for over a day now and I hope you guys can help me out. I want to create separate boxplots with ggplot2 for a set of environmental variables per a specific location (loc_nr) (and each location has varying number of data points). I only manage to create one large figure with many boxplots (indicating environmental variables) for all locations together on the x-axis. I would like to produce multiple small figures with the boxplots (one per location).

My data set (small part): all variable names are shifted towards the left, loc_nr should start at 01, so_temp at 0.230, etc.

```js
     loc_nr so_temp so_spcond  so_ph so_turbid so_chl1  so_o2  depth current water_fluc substrate   silt org_matter wood_nr connect veg_shore veg_water0 veg_water1  shade water_colour bycatch
1        01   0.230    -0.670  1.096    -0.386  -0.585  1.428 -0.468  -0.492     -1.008    -1.010 -0.863      3.933  -0.131  -0.706    -0.343     -0.277     -0.157 -0.291        0.639   3.318
2        01   0.178    -1.065  0.663    -0.315  -0.608  1.428 -0.406  -0.492     -1.008    -0.386 -0.863      3.933  -0.131  -0.706    -0.343      1.094     -0.157 -0.291       -1.481  -0.410
3        01   0.645    -0.670  0.969     0.185  -0.314  1.206 -0.220  -0.492     -1.008    -0.386  0.031      2.510  -0.131  -0.706    -0.343     -0.277     -0.157 -0.291       -1.481  -0.410
4        01   0.075    -0.276  0.383     0.224  -0.314  1.157 -0.096  -0.492     -1.008    -1.010  0.031      2.510  -0.131  -0.706    -0.343     -0.277     -0.157 -0.291       -1.481  -0.410
5        01   0.807    -0.276  0.332     1.779  -0.224  0.115 -0.468  -0.492     -1.008    -1.010  1.818      5.357  -0.033  -0.706    -0.343     -0.277     -0.157 -0.291       -0.774  -0.410
6        01   0.184    -0.276  0.816     0.363  -0.269  0.401 -0.406  -0.492     -1.008    -0.386  1.818      5.357  -0.033  -0.706    -0.343     -0.277     -0.157 -0.291       -0.774  -0.410
7        01   0.052    -1.065  1.452     0.839  -0.066 -0.117 -0.406  -0.492     -1.008    -0.386  0.031     -0.337  -0.131  -0.706    -0.343     -0.277     -0.157 -0.291       -1.481  -0.410
8        01   0.553    -0.276  0.561     0.576  -0.201  0.963 -0.282  -0.492     -1.008    -0.386  0.925     -0.337  -0.131  -0.706    -0.343     -0.277     -0.157 -0.291        0.639  -0.410
9        01   0.173    -0.407  0.791    -0.085  -0.269  0.634 -0.592  -0.492     -1.008     1.484  0.031     -0.337  -0.131  -0.706    -0.343     -0.277     -0.157  0.981       -0.774  -0.410
10       02   2.565    -0.144  1.223    -0.262  -0.698  2.039 -0.096  -0.492      0.990    -0.386 -0.863      2.510   0.261   0.471    -0.343     -0.277     -0.157 -0.291        0.639  -0.410
11       02   2.565    -0.144  1.223    -0.262  -0.698  2.039 -0.220  -0.492      0.990    -0.386  0.031      3.933  -0.033   0.471    -0.343     -0.277     -0.157 -0.291        0.639   1.454
12       02   2.565    -0.144  1.223    -0.262  -0.698  2.039  0.028  -0.492      0.990    -0.386  0.031      1.086  -0.033   0.471    -0.343     -0.277     -0.157 -0.291        0.639   1.454
13       02   2.565    -0.144  1.223    -0.262  -0.698  2.039 -0.220  -0.492      0.990    -0.386 -0.863      1.086  -0.131   0.471    -0.343     -0.277     -0.157 -0.291        0.639  -0.410
14       02   2.565    -0.144  1.223    -0.262  -0.698  2.039 -0.530  -0.492      0.990     1.484 -0.863     -0.337  -0.131   0.471    -0.343     -0.277     -0.157 -0.291        0.639  -0.410
15       02   2.565    -0.144  1.223    -0.262  -0.698  2.039 -0.406  -0.492      0.990     1.484 -0.863     -0.337  -0.131   0.471    -0.343     -0.277     -0.157 -0.291       -0.068  -0.410
16       02   2.565    -0.144  1.223    -0.262  -0.698  2.039 -0.592  -0.492      0.990     0.237 -0.863     -0.337  -0.131   0.471    -0.343     -0.277     -0.157  2.253       -0.774  -0.410
17       02   2.565    -0.144  1.223    -0.262  -0.698  2.039 -0.158  -0.492      0.990     0.237 -0.863     -0.337  -0.033   0.471    -0.343     -0.277     -0.157 -0.291        0.639  -0.410
18       02   2.565    -0.144  1.223    -0.262  -0.698  2.039 -0.406  -0.492      0.990    -1.010 -0.863     -0.337  -0.131   0.471    -0.343     -0.277     -0.157  0.981        0.639  -0.410
19       02   2.565    -0.144  1.223    -0.262  -0.698  2.039 -0.654  -0.492      0.990    -1.010 -0.863     -0.337  -0.131   0.471    -0.343     -0.277     -0.157 -0.291       -0.774  -0.410
20       02   2.565    -0.144  1.223    -0.262  -0.698  2.039 -0.592  -0.492      0.990    -1.010 -0.863     -0.337  -0.131   0.471    -0.343     -0.277     -0.157 -0.291       -0.774  -0.410
22       02   2.565    -0.144  1.223    -0.262  -0.698  2.039 -0.406  -0.492      0.990    -1.010 -0.863     -0.337  -0.131   0.471    -0.343     -0.277     -0.157  0.981        0.639  -0.410
23       02   2.565    -0.144  1.223    -0.262  -0.698  2.039 -0.654  -0.492      0.990    -1.010 -0.863     -0.337  -0.131   0.471    -0.343     -0.277     -0.157 -0.291       -0.774  -0.410
24       02   2.565    -0.144  1.223    -0.262  -0.698  2.039 -0.592  -0.492      0.990    -1.010 -0.863     -0.337  -0.131   0.471    -0.343     -0.277     -0.157 -0.291       -0.774  -0.410
25       03   0.818    -0.144 -0.966    -0.472  -0.641 -0.582 -0.220   2.026      0.990     0.237 -0.863     -0.337  -0.131   1.648    -0.343     -0.277     -0.157 -0.291        0.639  -0.410
27       03   0.818    -0.144 -0.966    -0.472  -0.641 -0.582 -0.592   2.026      0.990     1.484 -0.863     -0.337  -0.131   1.648    -0.343     -0.277     -0.157 -0.291        0.639  -0.410
28       03   0.818    -0.144 -0.966    -0.472  -0.641 -0.582 -0.530   2.026      0.990     1.484 -0.863     -0.337  -0.131   1.648    -0.343     -0.277     -0.157 -0.291        0.639  -0.410
29       05   1.706    -0.013  0.154    -0.405  -0.134  0.159 -0.096  -0.492      0.990    -0.386  1.818     -0.337  -0.131  -0.706    -0.343     -0.277     -0.157 -0.291        0.639   1.454
30       05   1.706    -0.013  0.154    -0.405  -0.134  0.159 -0.468  -0.492      0.990    -0.386  1.818     -0.337  -0.131  -0.706    -0.343     -0.277     -0.157 -0.291        0.639  -0.410
31       05   1.706    -0.013  0.154    -0.405  -0.134  0.159 -0.096  -0.492      0.990     0.237 -0.863     -0.337  -0.131  -0.706    -0.343     -0.277     -0.157 -0.291       -1.481  -0.410
32       05   1.706    -0.013  0.154    -0.405  -0.134  0.159 -0.530  -0.492      0.990     1.484 -0.863     -0.337  -0.131  -0.706    -0.343     -0.277     -0.157 -0.291       -1.481  -0.410
33       05   1.706    -0.013  0.154    -0.405  -0.134  0.159 -0.530  -0.492      0.990     1.484 -0.863     -0.337  -0.131  -0.706    -0.343     -0.277     -0.157 -0.291       -1.481  -0.410
44       07  -0.202    -0.013  0.561     2.957   4.310 -0.432 -0.220  -0.492     -1.008    -1.010  0.925     -0.337   0.359  -1.884    -0.343     -0.277     -0.157 -0.291        0.639  -0.410
45       07  -0.162     1.039  0.205    -0.104   0.047 -0.267  0.401  -0.492     -1.008    -1.010  1.818     -0.337  -0.131  -1.884    -0.343     -0.277     -0.157 -0.291        0.639  -0.410
46       07   0.132     1.039  0.154    -0.124   0.250 -0.325 -0.530  -0.492     -1.008    -1.010  2.712     -0.337  -0.131  -1.884    -0.343     -0.277     -0.157 -0.291        0.639  -0.410
```

And I'm using this code to produce the figure:

```
library(ggplot2)
dat.m <- reshape2::melt(env_alles,id.vars='loc_nr', measure.vars=c("so_temp", "so_spcond", "so_ph", "so_turbid", "so_chl1", "so_o2", "depth", "current",
                                                      "water_fluc", "substrate", "silt","org_matter", "wood_nr", "connect", "veg_shore",
                                                      "veg_water0", "veg_water1","shade", "water_colour", "bycatch")) 
p <- ggplot(dat.m) + geom_boxplot(aes(x=loc_nr, y=value, color=variable))
```

[This figure is produced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vfLo4.png)

I would like to have separate figures with (a set of environment variable) boxplots per location (in the case of this smaller dataset: location 01, 02, 03, 05, 07) shown in a grid.

Hope you guys can help me out solving this problem. Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You'll find the [`facet_wrap`](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/facet_wrap.html) function very helpful as you continue your learning and explorations into the `R` package [**`ggplot2`**](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/index.html)!

Is this what you had in mind?

```
ggplot(dat.m) + 
 geom_boxplot(aes(x = loc_nr, y=value, color=variable))+ 
 facet_wrap(~loc_nr, scales = 'free_x')
```

[image]

Since there are multiple `variable`s per `loc_nr`, we use the [`position = 'dodge'`](http://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/position_dodge.html) to adjust the horizontal position of the `variable`s.

Comment: It would be great to know why this was downvoted. Perhaps I could improve or remove my solution if I knew why.